# RML paragraph vertical align?

Tags: rml

I am working with RML and would like to align my text in the vertical middle of a paragraph. How might I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a table ? Like this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "rml.dtd" >
<document filename="example_08.pdf">
  <template showBoundary="0">
    <pageTemplate id="main">
      <pageGraphics/>
      <frame id="first" x1="100" y1="400" width="350" height="200" />
    </pageTemplate>
  </template>
  <stylesheet>
    <blockTableStyle id="blocktablestyle1">
      <blockValign value="MIDDLE" start="0,0" stop="-1,0"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
  </stylesheet>
  <story>
    <blockTable style="blocktablestyle1" colWidths="6cm,2cm">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <para>
              This is your paragraph. It's inside the &lt;para&gt; tags so the long 
              string of text is wrapped! You can set the horizontal space with 
              colWidths attribute on the blockTable.
          </para>
        </td>
        <td>The text valigned on the middle</td>
      </tr>
    </blockTable>
  </story>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

or else you can define like this for eg::

```
 <paraStyle name="terp_header" fontName="Helvetica-Bold" fontSize="15.0" leading="19" alignment="CENTRE" spaceBefore="12.0" spaceAfter="6.0"/>
```